# How to perform certain calculation when reading a file using php

Tags: php

I used the code below to scan a directory and is working fine.

Now I want to get **the total number of scanned files,
total number of line of codes for all the files and total filesize of all the files** so that I can save it.

At the moment:

1.) I can get number of scanned files via the code below

```
$filecount = count(glob($path ."/*"));
echo "file count: $filecount";
```

2.) I can get number of line codes for each files via

```
$count_line = count(file($file));
```

3.) I can get filesize for each files via

```
$filename_size =filesize($file);
```

please how do I get their sum total of the above, I guess I have to use something like `array_sum();`

can someone help me out

```
<?php

function saco($path){
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        $files = glob($path ."/*");

// get total number of files
$filecount = count(glob($path ."/*"));
echo "file count: $filecount";

//check if file exist in that directory
    if(count($files) > 0){
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach($files as $file){

                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo "$file"  . "<br>";

// get line of codes
echo $count_line = count(file($file));
// get filesize of each files
echo $filename_size =filesize($file);

                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    saco("$file");
                }
            }

        }

else{
            //echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}
saco("C:/xampp/htdocs/data");


?>
```

Comment: `$count_total += $count_line;`  in the loop `echo $count_total` after the loop. ditto for size

Comment: shows  Undefined variable: count_total

Comment: you need to initialise it before the loop `$count_total=0;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to initialise a counter for each item outside of the loop, and since you're counting recursively you also need to keep this counter outside of the function itself, or pass the current progress through for recursive calls.

working for your code here's an example that stores the totals in global variables that are updated from within the function.

```
<?php

$totals = [
    'files' => 0,
    'lines' => 0,
    'size' => 0,
];

function saco($path)
{
    global $totals;

    if (file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)) {
        $files = glob($path . "/*");

        // get total number of files
        $filecount = count($files);
        $totals['files'] += $filecount;

        //check if file exist in that directory
        if (count($files) > 0) {
            // Loop through retuned array
            foreach ($files as $file) {

                if (is_file("$file")) {

                    // get line of codes
                    $count_line = count(file($file));
                    // get filesize of each files
                    $filename_size = filesize($file);

                    $totals['lines'] += $count_line;
                    $totals['size'] += $filename_size;
                } else if (is_dir("$file")) {
                    // Recursively call the function if directories found
                    saco($file);
                }
            }

        } else {
            //echo "ERROR: No such file found in the directory.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: The directory does not exist.";
    }
}

saco("C:/xampp/htdocs/data");
```

Also note that using `file()` to count the number of lines works fine, but it will load the entire file into memory, meaning if you're working with large files you could cause memory errors.

If you know the files in question are going to be small it's not a problem, but if you need to handle large files you would need to use a different method

Answer (score 0):

before the loop initialise a new variable

```
$count_total=0;
```

in the loop add the line total

```
$count_total += $count_line;
```

after the loop, you can do what you like with `$count_total`

```
echo $count_total;
```

do the same thing for size.